# how to prevent mongoose save() from creating some schema default values?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this schema that have an expiry as a counter measure from felling data base with invalidated users so if the user doesn't do a certain validation his account will be deleted !! if he validates then the expiration gets removed, every thing is ok until now but if the user changes his email (after being activated ) what happens in that user.save() for some reason creates the expiration object again on the already existing model in DB even if the user has already been validated ! why does changing email causing this creation to happened ? I did another actions only the email change is creating this expires I tried to prevent it from happening by setting the expiration to null when changing email but it looks too awkward.
again thanks for the effort.

```js
const Userschema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        User: "",
        Name: "",
        Email: {
            type: 'string',
            require: [true, 'Please provide an Email'],
            unique: true,
            lowercase: true,
            validate: [validator.isEmail, 'please provide a valid email ']
        }// date the the user has been created !!!
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now()
        },// exparation is by defult
        expiration: {
            //unique: true,
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now(),
            expires: 60,
        },
    }
);

// removing experation logic if the user does a valid validation ! 
 const update2 = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
            { Email: req.body.Email }, {
            $unset: {
                'expiration': 'expires'
            }
})

// Solution but not clean. 
 const user = await User.findById(req.body.id)
    console.log(user, "useeeeeeeeeeeeeeeer");
    user.Email = newEmail
    user.expiration = ''
    user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            '_id': req.body.id,
        },
        {
            '$set': {
                Email: newEmail
            }
        }, { _id: true, new: true }
    )
```

This solved the issue still what is the diffrent between User.findById and using  save() , and using find one and update.